# How use realm-cli from a react native application?

Tags: react-native, realm

I need to execute a realm-cli command (disable or delete a user) from a mobile application that uses RealmDB, i didn't find any part of the docs that was related to do it.
I thought that i can use mongoClient but i didn't find any methods that allows me to execute raw cli commands.

I need to execute commands like:

`realm-cli users disable --app=<Your App ID> --user=<User ID>`

Font:
https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/users/delete-or-revoke/

Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to host the realm-cli and write a HTTP interface middleware to make these call.

I don't believe you can run the application on a mobile application as you would need access to spawning libraries. realm-cli is available open source so it would be possible to port the application to something like C++ (from golang) to make it executable for something like Android or iOS - but it may be cheaper to just buy a VPS somewhere (or even host it locally for a spell) and just pass the arguments to a web route.

Comment: True, I have not found another way...